# R: Warning Messages When Using The Optim() Function

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming.

**I am trying to numerically solve the following equation: b^4 + 9*b^2 - 9**

Here is my attempt to do this.

**Part 1:** First, I defined the function:

```
f <- function(b) {
  abs(b^4 + 9*b^2 - 9)
}
```

**Part 2:** Then, I tried to find the two roots of this function - I also chose some starting points:

```
root1 <- optim(-2, f)$par
root2 <- optim(2, f)$par

> root1
[1] -0.9530617
> root2
[1] 0.9530617
>
```

**Part 3:** Finally, I wanted to plot the results:

```
#create a series of points over which you want to plot the results:
b <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)

#main plot:
plot(b, f(b), type = "l", col = "blue", lwd = 2,
     main = "Intermediate results of f(b) = b^4 + 9b^2 - 9",
     xlab = "b", ylab = "f(b)")
abline(h = 0, col = "red", lty = 2)
points(root1, f(root1), pch = 19, col = "red")
points(root2, f(root2), pch = 19, col = "red")
legend("topright", legend = c("f(b)", "Roots"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = c(1, NA), pch = c(NA, 19))
```

[image]

**My Question:** While the code appears to run, I am concerned about the following warning messages that are produced:

```
> root1 <- optim(-2, f)$par
Warning message:
In optim(-2, f) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly
> root2 <- optim(2, f)$par
Warning message:
In optim(2, f) : one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly
```

**Can someone please help me understand if what I am doing is correct?**

Thanks!

**Note:** I can see that if I evaluate the original function and the proposed solution, the answer is very close to 0 - to me, this serves as a type of sanity check:

```
> f_root1 <- f(root1)
> f_root2 <- f(root2)

> f_root1
[1] 3.838697e-06
> f_root2
[1] 3.838697e-06
```

Comment: That is just a warning, not an error. Optimization is a difficult problem and there are many things that can go wrong, that's why `optim` has several optimizers for users to choose from. The suggested method `"Brent"` will, in your objective function's case, only find the positive roots for the initial values -2 or 2. Try `optim(-2, f, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par` instead.

Comment: `optim(-2, f, method = "Brent", lower = -1e6, upper = 1e6)$par` is what I tried and only gave the positive root.

Comment: @Rui Barradas: Thank you so much for your reply! In general, do you think what I have done is correct? Do you recommend a different method to numerically solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I say in comment, optimization is a difficult problem and there are many things that can go wrong, that's why `optim` has several optimizers for users to choose from.
When one of the methods `optim` uses is giving problems, try another one. Method `"L-BFGS-B"` seems to do the job correctly.

```r
f <- function(b) {
  abs(b^4 + 9*b^2 - 9)
}

(root1 <- optim(-2, f, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par)
#> [1] -0.9530612
(root2 <- optim(2, f, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par)
#> [1] 0.9530612

f(root1)
#> [1] 1.409797e-05
f(root2)
#> [1] 1.409797e-05
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To see that method `"Brent"` only finds the positive root, run

```r
(root3 <- optim(-2, f, method = "Brent", lower = -1e3, upper = 1e3)$par)
#> [1] 0.9530619
(root4 <- optim(2, f, method = "Brent", lower = -1e3, upper = 1e3)$par)
#> [1] 0.9530619
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>